# How to migrate EF + SQL Server to EF + WebServices + SQL Server to create a secure solution?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

We currently have a WinForms application that accesses our SQL Server database through Entity Framework. The solution was built with database-first methods. Our database is hosted in Microsoft's Azure SQL services.

We need to secure the application connection to the database but the application will reside on employee laptops that need to work from anywhere. Currently the firewall is open to any IP because obviously the IP address for employees change depending on where they are located.

We need to introduce a web services layer but I don't want to run an entire website just to provide a web service to authenticate against. Creating an entire MVVC between the database and a web service, configuring packages, authentication, etc. just seems a bit much just to wrap the EF / DB communication with AD authentication.

How can we add a web service layer that is seamless for Entity Framework that will allow for Azure AD authentication? Is there an Azure service that works with EF to provide SQL Server access with better authentication? What options are out there that we don't know about?

Update: Adding a little to narrow down the question...
Is there a solution or Azure service that can provide a secure web service layer between EF (easily) and our SQL database? For example, does EF work with Azure Web Apps or Azure Mobile Apps without needing separate models for the web services layer?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: EF and authentication are not related in any way. This question is way too broad.

Comment: I wasn't implying they were related. I was outlining our application structure. How would you suggest I narrow the question so it is not so broad? Some helpful recommendations would be nice instead of criticism.

Comment: I don't agree that it's too broad.  But it is going to be largely opinion based once you get past the basic "yes, there is" sort of answer.  What to choose from the options available is where a question like this goes off the rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use token-based authentication as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token).

A file-based authentication is also available as explained [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md).

Comment: The question here is off-topic (very broad). Aside from that: link-only answers are not valid; links rot and die. And it requires someone to leave StackOverflow to discover the answer.